# c# - show SplashScreen in Winform until MainForm shown

Tags: c#, splash-screen

I have a winforms application and it flickers when opening. I think this is because the winform framework is loaded first and then the components are loaded. I thought of SplashScreen as a solution to this, but all SplashScreen screens, including Stackoverflow, show a SplashScreen form in front of the form while the MainForm is loading and the SplashScreen screen disappears afterwards.

However, I want the MainForm to load in the background while SplashScreen is shown, and when the loading is finished, SplashScreen disappears, and MainForm comes to the screen without any flickering. I don't want it to depend on any `timer`, and neither does `Thread.Sleep`. For me these are not solving the problem, but sweeping it under the rug.

For example, as in PhotoShop. There, SplashScreen opens, all components are loaded and when SplashScreen closes, MainForm opens without any blinking. How can I achieve this?

I tried this, but it was frustration.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApp;

internal static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(true);

        var app = new MyApplication();
        app.Run(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs());
    }
}
public class MyApplication : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
    {
        MainForm = new MyMainForm();
    }
    protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
    {
        SplashScreen = new MySplashScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly that flicker? The Form, the controls, both? Do you have the `DoubleBuffered` property of the main Form set to `True`? Do you run some lengthy routine (ex. reading from db...etc.) in the Form's ctor or/and `Load` event. Some details and maybe a screenshot to narrow down the flickering reasons.

Answer (score -2):

I think something like this should get you somewhere:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();

    var splash = new SplashScreen();
    splash.Show();
    
    // I call DoEvents here to make sure that the splash-screen is properly shown.
    Application.DoEvents();

    // Just a sleep to mimick your load or init procedure
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    splash.Close();

    // Form1 is my 'main application' form.
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Comment: I wish you had read the question.  `I don't want it to depend on any timer, and neither does Thread.Sleep. For me these are not solving the problem, but sweeping it under the rug.` And the other problem, which library cointains `ApplicationConfiguration`?

Comment: I'm not saying it depends on any timer.  The Thread.Sleep is there to replace whatever loading you have.  The ApplicationConfiguration class is a compiler generated class and the Initialize method performs EnableVisualStyles, SetCompatiblityTextRenderingDefault, etc....   That line is auto-generated when you start a new WinForms project in VS.NET 2022.  But whatever .